# Firestore ¿Manejar Cuando no existe el documento en una Coleccion"?

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Me ha surgido el siguiente problema pero no logro dar con la forma de abordarlo.

Estoy comprobando si existe un documento en una Coleccion de datos en Firebase, para realizar una tarea u otra en funcion de si existe o no el documento

En el caso de que exista ese documento recojo el valor de un campo , hasta aqui todo me va de perlas.

En el caso de que no exista ese documento quiero lanzar un AlertDialog, aqui ya el programa me peta mostrnadome un:

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String juanmanuel.apppesastfg.Modelos.UsuarioSigueRutina.getIdRutina()' on a null object reference

Segun he podido leer en un libro de Firebase, tras realizar la consulta, realizamos un onComplete() para comprobar que se ha completado y verificamos con un isSuccessfull() para comprobar que se ha completado con exito.
Completado con exito entiendo que es haya o no haya documentos en esa coleccion ya que tras realizar pruebas veo que tanto  encuentre el documento como si no lo encuentra realiza lo que hay dentro del isSuccesfull().
Entonces lo que entiendo es que si no existe el documento en la coleccion me devuelve un null.
¿Como puedo controlar que si no existe ese documento me lanze el metodo lanzarDialog()? porque intentnado hacer un if(task.getResult.equal(null)) pero me muestra el nullpointexception...

Muchas gracias a todos.

usuarioSigueRutinaRef.document(idUsuario).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                if(task.getResult().equals(null)){
                    lanzarDialog();
                }else {
                    UsuarioSigueRutina usuarioSigueRutina = task.getResult().toObject(UsuarioSigueRutina.class);
                    Toast.makeText(MenuPrincipalActivity.this, usuarioSigueRutina.getIdRutina(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }else{
                Log.e("Firebase","Se ha producido un error al realizar el get",task.getException());
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Según la documentación de Firestore, si consultas un documento que no existe, Firestore devolverá un objeto vacío y el método `exists()`, del objeto, devolverá false.

Sabiendo eso, tu código debería verse así:

```
@Override
public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {

    if(task.isSuccessful()){

        if(!task.getResult.exists()){

            lanzarDialog();

        } else {

            UsuarioSigueRutina usuarioSigueRutina = task.getResult().toObject(UsuarioSigueRutina.class);
            Toast.makeText(MenuPrincipalActivity.this, usuarioSigueRutina.getIdRutina(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    } else {

        Log.e("Firebase","Se ha producido un error al realizar el get",task.getException());
    }
}});
```

Otra cosa, Firebase te da como resultado, de la consulta, successful porque la consulta fue exitosa. El que un documento no exista en Firebase no quiere decir que la consulta falle. La consulta falla si durante el proceso de consulta ocurre un error, como por ejemplo, que falle la conexión a Internet. En ese caso si te daría como resultado canceled.

Referencia:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data?hl=es-419#get_a_document

Comment: Buenos dias,
antes de hacer el equal intente tambien solucionarlo haciendo lo mismo que tu me has dicho, por alguna razon que desconozco el task recibe algun tipo de objeto ya que tampoco puedo darle solucion haciendo uso de :
If(task.getResult() == null)


https://subefotos.com/ver/?cb7d75d9a675459b30fb0855a8114012o.png#codigos

Comment: Imprime el objeto en consola para ver que te muestra. Log.i("getResult()", task.getResult().toString());

Comment: Acabo de actualizar la respuesta. Mira a ver si ahora funciona.

Comment: Excelente David jeje ha funcionado no se como no vi el metodo ese cuando lo chequee jeje muchas gracias ^^

Comment: Genial ya esta hecho, ayer intente hacerlo pero me decia que al ser nuevo y no tener mas de 15 puntos o algo parecido mis votos no se tenian en cuenta jeje